# Отправляет ли плагин Contact Form 7 письма на почту с locahost?

Tags: wordpress, denwer, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

На Localhost установлен WordPress. На нем использую плагин Contact form 7. При отправке сообщения, появляется надпись, что заявка успешно отправлена, но на почту письмо не приходит. Хотелось бы узнать: дело в локальном сервере? И при переводе на хостинг в инете все заработает?

Comment: Смотря какой localhost и смотря чем идет отправка, sendmail или через SMTP

Comment: Ставил денвер. На WP пробовал устанавливать плагин отправки через SMTP - так же ничего не приходит

Comment: Забудьте вы денвер уже, это прошлое столетие. Openserver рулит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На денвере (и вообще на Windows) нет phpmail. Отправлять просто нечем. Есть эмуляторы. Денвер тот письма в файл пишет.

K используемой терминологии: Не "локалхост", а "на Windows".