# Не приходят сообщения на почту с помощью функции mail php

Tags: php, wordpress

В чем может быть проблема? mail возвращает true, то есть, он отправил сообщение (вроде как) почта моя вида post@yandex.ru, но никакого сообщения нет. Сотню раз отправлял форму. Подскажите.

```html
<form class="form" action="<?php the_permalink()?>" method="post">
    <?php
    //user posted variables
    $name = $_POST['message_name'];
    $tel = $_POST['message_tel'];
    $email = $_POST['message_email'];
    $text = $_POST['message_text'];
    $comment = ($text) ? 'Комментарий: ' . $text .';' : '';

    $message =
        'Новая заявка' . "\n" .
        'от ' . $name .'.'. "\n" .
        'Телефон: ' . $tel .';' . "\n" .
        'email: ' . $email .';' . "\n" . $comment;

    //php mailer variables
    $to = get_option('admin_email');
    $subject = "Сообщение от ".get_bloginfo('name');
    $headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
      'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

    if ($name && $tel && $email) {
        $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        if($sent) echo 'Есть';//message sent!
        else echo 'Пить';//message wasn't sent
    };

    ?>
    <input name="message_name" value="<?php echo $_POST['message_name']?>" class="form__input" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Ф. И. О"/>
    <input name="message_tel" value="<?php echo $_POST['message_tel']?>" class="form__input" type="tel" required="required" placeholder="Телефон"/>
    <input name="message_email" value="<?php echo $_POST['message_email']?>" class="form__input" type="email" required="required" placeholder="E-mail"/>
    <textarea name="message_text" class="form__textarea" placeholder="Ваш комментарий"><?php echo $_POST['message_text']?></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="button1 contacts__button button">
</form>
```

Эта форма подключается wordress в другой файл

```
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/form')?>
```

Comment: посмотрите в спаме того ящика, который $to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во `From` нужно подставлять адрес на домене с которого идёт отправка. На нек серверах требуется даже заведения ящика wordpress@домен.сайта

Адрес для ответов - `Reply-to`.

А вообще для ВП лучше использовать готовые плагины.

Comment: Если я работаю на open server, я смогу отправить себе сообщение?
Я на поставил после `From` wordpress@roof.ru (что соответствует домену на опен сервере), однако все равно ничего не пришло

Comment: нет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757557/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd-contact-form-7-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%81-locahost/757684#757684 Точнее "отправить"  из ВП можешь. Отправить с сервера нет. И вообще это уже вопрос к опенсерверу, а не ВП.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!